# How do I use sed or tr to remove a counter with brackets

Tags: sed, counter, brackets, tr

How do I use sed or tr to remove a counter with brackets and a tab

Input:

```
[51971] 207.99.88.182 - - [07/Apr....
```

Output:

```
207.99.88.182 - - [07/Apr....
```

The counter part has been driving me nuts as I was able to remove everything else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using sed, I would advise lowering the overheads by using cut, as below:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- < file.ext
```

This will chop off the first field (the counter in your case), removing the need to parse and evaluate a regular expression.

If the fields are tab delimited rather than space delimited, then you can remove the first parameter as shown:

```
cut -f2- < file.ext
```

Comment: Perhaps expand on this to make it a more thorough answer.

Comment: "cut -f2- < file.ext" Worked great, was not aware it could deal with fields thought it was character only. Thanks for everybody's help it was much appreciated!

Comment: +1 because you seem to notice that the OP said 'remove a counter with brackets and a tab'. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

this sed line works for the example:

```
sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

e.g.:

```
kent$  echo "[51971] 207.99.88.182 - - [07/Apr...."|sed 's/[^ ]* //'
207.99.88.182 - - [07/Apr....
```